# How to Identify the Page overflow in Aspose PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, aspose.pdf, aspose.html

I am converting a HTML content to PDF using Aspose .Net API's. HTML content contains table which has dynamic data, so if the data is more date, then the table is overflown into second page.

Is there a way to Identify the page overflown in my document, because I want insert an empty page in between, whenever an overflow happens.

**Code Snippet:**

```
// Creating Doc
 Aspose.Pdf.Document document = new Document();
for(var contentModel in listcontentModel)
{
 Page page = document.Pages.Add();
string HTMLContent = //HTMLContent -- using contentModel to build HTML;
-- Sometime page overflow happens because of huge HTML content
HtmlFragment printHtml = new HtmlFragment(text);
page.Paragraphs.Add(printHtml);
}
document.Save(filePath);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: We have logged your requirement as PDFNET-51870. We will inform you once there is an update available on it. I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.